# elgg plugin URL change

Tags: url, plugins, elgg

I have a plugin names "Groups" whose URL has to be changed to "Projects" in Elgg 1.7.15.. I have changed every "group" keyword to "project" and also the folder names. I included a separate package called "project" in the Elgg core. But still it shows an error. Could anybody give any pointers on that.

Answer (score 2):

In the 1.7 series the group plugin is a part of the elgg core. You cant simply change every key words for groups. YOu can try the following steps

- Create a new page handler for the groups called projects and place it below the groups plugin
- Register a new entity URL for the groups
- Change the language strings
- Create a 404 forwarder so that all the previous links get redirected to the new page handler

The better option is upgrade to 1.8 (which is having a better code structure) and just do implement the four steps above in a new plguin and place it below the groups plugin and you are done. We have implemented the same for the plugin store in our site @ http://www.webgalli.com/elgg_plugins/all .